# Installing Collective Access

Tags: windows-server-2008, php

I am VERY new to installing any type of server program and to running any opensource type software in general.

I am running Windows Server 2008R2. I want to install Collective Access to run locally only on my Intranet at home. So my host is localhost. I sucessfully installed PHP and MYSQL.
I installed CA in this directory C:/inetpub/wwwroot/collectiveaccess.

1. I do not want to send mail through collective access. Will it install without all the email information? Can I comment those requirements out in the global config and setup.php file?
2. I am getting this error:

   ```
   Configuration file is missing for hostname 'localhost'
   this is what I have in the set up file:
   define("__CA_WEB_ROOT_DIR__", "c:inetpub/wwwroot");
   define("__CA_URL_ROOT__", "/collectiveaccess");
   define("__CA_SITE_HOSTNAME__", "localhost");
   define("__CA_DB_HOST__", 'localhost');
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Simple coding mistake.. c:inetpub/wwwroot .... missing backslash /
Should be c:/inetpub/wwwroot